# unrecognized selector sent to class 0x51e8'

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this error, when I am trying to pass a uitextfeild value from my tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in my uitableview over to my nsobject class however when I click the uitableviewcell that I have coded to pass the uitextfield value I receive the error listed below.

//DBAccess.h

```
    @interface DBAccess : NSObject {

        NSString *receiveCodeText;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *receiveCodeText;

- (NSMutableArray *) getAllMakes;
    - (void) setPassCode:(NSString *)theCode;
```

//DBAccess.m

```
//...
//Need to set my string here..
- (void)setPassCode:(NSString *)theCode{
    receiveCodeText = theCode;
}
//...
- (NSMutableArray *)getAllMakes{
//...
const char *value = [receiveCodeText cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //reciveCodeText is set in RootViewController and passed to value here
    [receiveCodeText release];
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, value, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

//....
}
```

//viewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    searchTableViewController *searchTable = [[searchTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"searchTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Make";
            //Pass code number over to DBAccess class
            [DBAccess setPassCode:codeText.text];
        } break;
        case 2: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Mod";
        } break;
        case 3: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Method";
        } break;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchTable animated:YES];
    [searchTable release];
}
```

And this is the error I am getting.

```
> 2011-06-13 13:05:33.433
> Code1.6[1318:207] +[DBAccess
> setPassCode:]: unrecognized selector
> sent to class 0x51e8 2011-06-13
> 13:05:33.477 Code1.6[1318:207] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught
> exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '+[DBAccess setPassCode:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to class
> 0x51e8'
> *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                     
> 0x00e45be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                  
> 0x00f9a5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>   2   CoreFoundation                   
> 0x00e477bb +[NSObject(NSObject)
> doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3  
> CoreFoundation                     
> 0x00db7366 ___forwarding___ + 966     4  
> CoreFoundation                     
> 0x00db6f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>   5   Code1.6                       
> 0x000028ff -[RootViewController
> tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] +
> 253   6   UIKit                        
> 0x00331794 -[UITableView
> _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
> + 1140    7   UIKit                               0x00327d50 -[UITableView
> _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
> + 219     8   Foundation                          0x0003a7f6 __NSFireDelayedPerform +
> 441   9   CoreFoundation               
> 0x00e26fe3

> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
> + 19  10  CoreFoundation                      0x00e28594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
>   11  CoreFoundation                   
> 0x00d84cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817  12 
> CoreFoundation                     
> 0x00d84240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>   13  CoreFoundation                   
> 0x00d84161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    14
> GraphicsServices                   
> 0x016e7268 GSEventRunModal + 217  15 
> GraphicsServices                   
> 0x016e732d GSEventRun + 115   16  UIKit
> 0x002ca42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
>   17  Code1.6                       
> 0x0000230c main + 102     18  Code1.6    
> 0x0000229d start + 53 ) terminate
> called after throwing an instance of
> 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setPassCode seems to be a class instance  method and not a static method, yet you are trying to access it as a static method, you must declare yur method like so in order for it to be static

```
+(void)setPassCode....
```

Your program crashes because you are calling the method on the class itself instead of on an instance of the class..
Hope this helps

Comment: ahh.. that make sense! however at build time I now have instance varaible accessed in class metod warning... and when I click the tableviewcell it just crashes no error nothing.. weird or what.

Comment: You should of had some warning before.. Not sure what you are doing now however, did u change the declaration and implementation  to both have + ?

Comment: Okay so the warning went away but its still just falling over each time I hit the tableviwcell... I have read around and it could be from trying to access an area of memory not allocated/available...

Comment: Which line does it do it in? If it's the same try sending some other string in maybe that label is the culprit ... Any message from the console?

Comment: No I have figured out what the problem is. I have defined the method with a '+' - that makes it a class (static) method. and you cannot access any instance variables in such methods by definition (since it is NOT an instance method you cannot access instance variables).

So I need to figure out how to get around this, I have tried creating another instance method that is passed its variable from the class method. however this is not working any ideas?

Comment: Seems that you are trying to keep state, in that case you style make the method an instance method and create a new instance of the class and hold on to it in the tableview class... If you don't wnt to do that you can make that field a static field nd I'll be able to accescs it through the class method